# Can we install SharePoint 2010 on Windows server 2012

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2012, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-documents

One straight question.

Can we install SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012??

If we **can** install, Can someone please provide with some links to proper documentation on how to install it?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet.  Service Pack 2 will allow support, but since there is not installation media for it yet, you cannot go directly to Service Pack 2.  Once the Slip Stream Package for SP2 is release (or a full installation media), Server 2012 will be supported.  I would watch this page for updates on that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2724471/en-us

Comment: I'm still waiting for the slipstreamed version. its a shame i cant install 2010 standard on my 2012 server.